# Two forms in one model. Combining values for table databases

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-database

I have simple model in django that looks like :

```
class TimeTable(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time= models.CharField(choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    end_time = models.CharField(choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    day1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day5 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day6 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day7 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

for this model I have 2 forms :

```
class TimeTableForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeTable
        fields = ['title ', 'start_time', 'end_time']


class WeekDayForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeTable
        fields = ['day1', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4', 'day5', 'day6', 'day7']
```

Now In views.py I need to save this values into database

```
def schedule(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TimeTableForm(request.POST)
        day_week = WeekDayForm(request.POST)   
        if all([form.is_valid(), day_week.is_valid()]):
            form.save()
            day_week.save()
```

I'm new in Django so I was thinking that this values will be combined into one and I will get proper data but for every one submit I get two separated objects in database for example

```
title | 8:00 | 10:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

      |      |       | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

but I should get

```
title | 8:00 | 10:00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

As you see this two forms values are separated in database (probably for person who have more much common with django it is obvious) there is an option to combine this two into one ?

Comment: Why do you have two forms?

Comment: @DanielRoseman maybe it is stupid but in html i have two different style for them I mean : `'{{ schedule_form.as_p }} {{ week_day.as_table }}'`. It was fast way to do that

Comment: It won't work like that, make one single form and style each field separately. Look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually